# Spring @ConfigurationProperties Root Config

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

When writing up spring configuration via `@ConfigrationProperties` is there a way to wire up the root value of the config.

My config is something like

```
foo.bar=hello
foo.bar.baz=world
```

How can I get the value out of the `foo.bar` variable. Currently I have this

```
@Configuration
@ConfigurationProperties("foo.bar")
public class FooBar {
    private String baz;

    // Getters and setters...
}
```

I can't change the schema. The properties are coming from env variables `FOO_BAR` and `FOO_BAR_BAZ`

Comment: Just bind the properties using `@Value`, that is probably the easiest in this case.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `@EnableConfigurationProprties(FooBar.class)` to tell spring boot to create a bean for your configuration. Something like this should work for you:

```
@Configuration
@EnableConfigurationProperties(FooBar.class)
class MyConfiguration {
    final FooBar fooBar;

    MyConfiguration(FooBar fooBar) {
        this.fooBar = fooBar;
    }

    @ConfigurationProperties("foo.bar")
    static class FooBar {
        String baz;
        // ....
    }

    @Bean
    MyBean myBean() {
        // use this.fooBar here...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Annotate your class with the `@PropertySource` annotation and add a variable to fetch it.

```
    @PropertySource("classpath:config.properties")
public class FooBar {
    @Value("${foo.bar}")
        private String baz;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I am writing this for someone who might be in the same situation:

1. Use constructors in your class.
2. you can also use class level `@Component`

```
@Configuration
@ConfigurationProperties("foo.bar")
@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
public class FooBar {

    private String baz;
}
```

for annotations `@Data`, `@AllArgsConstructor`, `@NoArgsConstructor`, install and use [lombok dependency](https://howtodoinjava.com/automation/lombok-eclipse-installation-examples/).